# How can I replace stock download manager that Google Play uses?

Tags: google-play-store, download-manager

Yesterday I upgraded my rooted LG Optimus One (P500) running v20g 2.3.3 to CM10 (unofficial) 4.1.1 through [this](http://www.theandroidsoul.com/cyanogenmod-10-cm10-based-android-4-1-jelly-bean-comes-optimus-one-p500/) post.

Since the new ROM is unofficial and is in alpha/beta stage there are few known problems. I am able to live up with those problems just to enjoy the new Jelly Bean.  However one undocumented problem about download manager was discovered yesterday, which proved to me nasty.

When I attempt to install any app from Google Play Store, a progress bar appears saying "Downloading..." and the numerical progress indicator 'x/y Kb done' does not come up. At first I thought it should be problem with my WiFi, but other application seems to access Internet correctly.  In concurrence to this behavior, the LEDs in my WiFi modem does not blink, which it usually does when there is a WiFi activity.  Even small apps in the order of 150 Kb takes long time and eventually ends with error.  However, I accidentally noticed that a combination of simultaneous downloads of more than one app, cancelling and starting again etc, made FEW of the downloads to actually progress while other still linger.  So, it is clear that the download manager that Google Play Store relies on is trouble some in my case.

My question is how can I replace that download manager? Installing other download manager does not help as Google Play still uses the troublesome native one only.

Any ideas on how I can use some other download manager **for Google Play** or to mend the troublesome one?

BTW, I had tried: Turbo Download Manager, Download Manager for Android. They do not detect the download when i press "install" button in Google Play Store for an app. Trying other download manager is still a big pain as I have to download APK from other sites and transfer to my SD card to install.

Comment: BTW, if some one is curious about how Jellybean performs on LG P500 (600Mhz, 512Mb): it rocks! I could not tell difference between Gingerbread and Jellybean in terms of speed. Other usual UI enhancements are great too...

Comment: Did you find the answer? I also want to replace the Download Manager in order to be able to have control over what is actually downloading. Basically to be able to use App Store and "disable" automatic system updates.

Answer (score 1):

While you intend to replace the stock download manager, but keep access to Google Play Store, since it's your trusted market, before that, you should try to find the reason as to why are you having troubles downloading apps:

## Troubleshooting Download Issues

1. Is the device supported by Google Play Store?

   You can confirm this from the [Supported Devices List](http://support.google.com/googleplay/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1727131) <sup>last updated 2012/06/29</sup>
2. Common quick checks:

   - Restart your phone, then try downloading the app again.
   - Confirm there is connectivity to either wireless or cellular networks on your device.
3. If behind a firewall, ensure that TCP and UDP 5228 ports aren’t blocked (they are required for Google Play).
4. Clear cache and data of both the Google Play Store app and the Download manager:

   1. Visit Menu > Settings > Applications > Manage applications;
   2. Tab over to "All";
   3. Select the Google Play Store app, and then tap "Clear data" and "Clear cache";
   4. Select Download manager and tap "Clear data" and "Clear cache".

Aditional information for troubleshooting can be found at [Google Play: Troubleshoot an issue](http://support.google.com/googleplay/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=1046719&parent=1100168&ctx=topic).

---

## Alternatives

#### Other App discovery Method

[Appbrain](http://www.appbrain.com/), an app discovery service that as per your request still uses Google Play Store as the source for the downloads provide.

It features a great instant download tool ([AppBrain App Market](http://www.appbrain.com/app/appbrain-app-market/com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.apps)), a nice search function, a very clear interface and you can [sign-in](http://www.appbrain.com/login) with your Google account.

*One side note: This app still downloads via the stock download manager.*

#### Alternative Markets

Alternative markets have their own download manager. They may be a solution, provided the issue does not lie with your current unofficial ROM:

- [Amazon Appstore for Android](http://www.amazon.com/mobile-apps/b/ref=topnav_storetab_mas?ie=UTF8&node=2350149011)

  While an alternative market, I've received a notice from the website stating:

  > The Amazon Appstore is only available to customers located in the United States.
- [GetJar](http://www.getjar.com/)

  Launched in 2004, it grows every day, counts 600.000+ apps, and 450.000+ registered developers. As an independent app store, not tied to any particular handset or carrier, it comes as an alternative solution for you.
- [AndroidPIT](http://www.androidpit.com/)

  AndroidPIT is a Web 2.0 network and Android blog. Was created to bring together Android experts, enthusiasts and developers. Apps are tested, at least one every day and reviews are published to help users on their decisions.
- [SlideME](http://slideme.org/)

  Founded back in 2008, SlideME provides a 'Managed App-Store Service' and builds solutions as per market requirements.

Comment: Thanks @Zuul, appreciate your input. I am bit skeptic about other markets. Hence I would like to stick to Google Play Store. I will rather download the APK through my computer and transfer to my phone's SD card.

Comment: yesterday I installed the tool from AppBrain App Market and attempted to download an app. The app takes me through few screens and finally it lands in app's page of Google Play Store where it asks me to accept terms and conditions. After agreeing the download takes place through the same troublesome download manager. Just FYI

Comment: @Narayan: AppBrain is app discovery, not alternative market, it still uses Play Market for installations, try another alternative that does have their own download server, like Amazon AppStore or GetJar or SlideME.

Comment: @LieRyan There, as requested, a more extended solution, covering all from troubleshooting to alternative markets, to app discoveries services! Tks by the "push" :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try dettach your google play account from your device in settings accounts, then relog in,
Some custom roms you will not get ota updates via google in a rooted device.