# Accidentally Uninstalled Download Manager

Tags: download-manager

I was using my phone ASUS Zenfone Max when I accidentally uninstalled my [Download Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDfuX.jpg), I thought it was a random pop up download when you go to sites so I deleted it. After that, when I tried download photos from Google, a window popped saying "The Browser has stopped working". I have also tried to download from Google Play Store, but it won't let me download any apps at all. I also tried opening the "Downloads", that can be found on the settings, but this pop up window shows up *see photo*. I tried downloading an apk file using another download manager (named ADP), it got installed, but when I tried to download photos again from browser and apps on Play Store it still won't let me. I think the reason is that the one I deleted is the built in app. I don't know if I reset my phone will help me to download files again. Please help, I have already searched the internet but I still can't find a solution.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26797/how-can-i-replace-stock-download-manager-that-google-play-uses?rq=1

Comment: Is your device rooted? If not, it is odd that you were able to uninstall your Download Manager (probably `com.android.providers.downloads`), as it is a system app. Are you sure that it isn't just disabled? As for why both the Browser and the Play Store aren't working, it is due to them handing over the download to the Download Manager, which, in your case, is missing. Since those apps expect the abovementioned to be present, an alternative one won't work.

Answer (score 1):

My big brother has the same phone (ASUS Zenfone Max). He installed an app where he can send built in apps to other devices via APK. So he sent the Download Manager APK on my phone, tried to install it but the "com.android.providers.downloads is not working" still keept popping out. In the end I decided to Factory Reset my phone. And it worked.

My phone is not rooted so I was shocked that I deleted a built in app. Maybe because of the pop up download I got when I went to a website (I was checking sites to download Korean Dramas). I read from forums that if they deleted a built in app and chose factory reset there was no assurance that the said app will be in the device, so I presumed that by sending and installing the original apk file of DM and by choosing Factory Reset the system will recognize the installed apk file and reset it.

Comment: You can never delete a system app through Settings app. Since the device was't rooted, it is clear that you ended up disabling it which was reverted to stock condition after factory reset. Your action of sideloading an APK didn't make any effect, because factory reset clears everything a user did before reset, including sideloading any APK (unless moved to non-data, non-cache partitions). ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you reset your device. It reinstalls all the base applications. But be sure to backup all the files.

Comment: Resetting a device only wipes the user's data. It could help in case the OP *deactivated* the Download Manager, but not if they actively uninstalled it.

Comment: Resetting some devices reinstalls the base system in that device from scratch. Anyway that's how it goes with my device. If you backup your data there is no problem resetting a device. It should work.

Comment: It may work for a stock device with a flashable copy of the stock system already provided by the manufacturer and if the stock recovery has already been instructed to do so. It won't work for custom ROMs, though.

Comment: That's the risk of installing  custom roms

Comment: Not much of a risk, since one just needs to reflash a zip, with no userdata loss. Anyways, let's wait for the asker to test the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Android version . Get the app file from someone with the same Android version . Install the file and convert it to system file and reboot .
Next time don't mess with system apps

Answer (score -1):

If your phone is rooted and custom recovery is installed then you can reflash gapps it will solve your problem(choose gapps according to your mobile architecture) [open gapps link here](http://opengapps.org).

**Disclaimer** I'm not responsible if you bricked your device. Do it your own responsibility.

Comment: -1: the Download Manager is a system app which has nothing to do with the Gapps.