# Hindi font not display in htc_salsa_C510e_android2.0.3?

Tags: htc, fonts, sony-xperia-arc

In My app display Hindi font.
so i use the **DroidHindi.ttf** font to display  the font.
and i run this app output in **SonyXperia_MT27i** like this!
[Sony_Xperia_MT27i_android_4.0.4 Image screen][image]

and same app run in **htc_salsa_C510e_android2.0.3**
Display this type output[image: htc_salsa_C510e_android2.0.3]

Please any help me.
what is the problem i don't know.

Comment: If this is about how to code or configure your source to display characters, then the better place for these questions are at {SO}. Else, if you are asking this from an end user's perspective, then the ROM of HTC does not have font AND ability to render complex glyphs.

Comment: @Narayanan may be this is not answer.if display in other device and never in htc?it's the problem of htc?

Comment: Yes. Take a look at [my related](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25359/how-to-make-an-android-device-to-display-complex-rendering-of-indic-characters) question. In 2.x.x, without manufacturer or ROM developer's intervention it is not possible render complex scripts like Indian languages.

Comment: @Narayanan yes are u right sir.but problem is where?my pm want result of problem.he see me the both device and ask for result.

Comment: Let us continue this in a [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7922/androidenthusiasts-hindicharactersnotdisplaying)

Comment: That is related to libskia which is responsible for font-rendering, unfortunately in your case, it requires 1) rooted handset, 2) custom ROM that can support this kind of font (CM has additional support for this kind of thing in respect to right-to-left fonts).  It is not as simple as taking `libskia` from another ROM and drop it into your ROM as it needs to be rebuilt from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer and my [comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/41227/how-to-install-full-unicode-fonts/41771#comment56552_41771) about replacing a font file `Droidsansfallback.ttf`. I am sure you can search and find many file sharing sites sharing this file. You can also extract the font file from any of the Android device that you may have.

After replacing the font file and restarting the phone, chances are pretty high that you might not be able to see the word हिन्दी as you see here, rather you might see it split as ह ि न्द ी without spaces. Nothing much you can do if it shows up like this as I my [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25359/how-to-make-an-android-device-to-display-complex-rendering-of-indic-characters) is all about that :(

Comment: i will try.then reply you dear