# which browser can display all unicode charecters on Android os?

Tags: applications, 4.4-kitkat, browser, apk

Iam looking for a browser, which can display all unicode charecters?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a case of adding a Unicode font to the browser. [Instructions](http://uni.hilledu.com/android-uc-browser-font-settings) for UCBrowser involve creating a **font** folder inside the **UCDownloads** folder, then copying the Unicode font file into it. There isn't actually any 'install' program to run as such. A font that seems to work is the [Unifoundry standard TTF](http://unifoundry.com/unifont.html) suggested by [Shawn Redmond](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/41227/how-to-install-full-unicode-fonts) - tested on http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/unicode/unidata07.html.