# Tamil Font not supporting in Facebook and tamil websites

Tags: fonts

I am suresh from riyadh, sAUDI ARABIA last week i bought Samsung-Galaxy-S-DUOS-GT-S7562 mobile ..    i am facing a problem for Tamil font not supporting in facebook and tamil news.. Please help me..

Comment: Please check out the following question an its answers: [How to make an Android device to display complex rendering of Indic characters?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/25359/16575)

Answer (score 0):

You Must install the India Version of Firmware for your mobile. you can get the indian version of the firmare at [SAMMOBILE SITE](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/1/?model=GT-S7562&pcode=INS#firmware)