# How to add new language Unicode range to Android OS

Tags: languages, localization

**Background**

Sri Lanka has its own language called Sinhala with its own Unicode range (0D80 - 0DFF) and set of rendering rules. Currently Android phones do not support this language (but Linux and Windows do). We have built a temporary solution using JavaScript to read Sinhala in Android but we face issue when need to input by users.

**Questions**

1. How can we add a new built-in Unicode range to Android?
2. Do I need to request this from Google or can we do it ourselves?
3. Do we need to request this from Android manufacturers such as Samsung, HTC, Acer?
4. How can we create a Android keyboard that is suitable to our language.

Comment: I don't understand this, but I found it on Google: http://sinhala.kalingasblog.com/2010/07/25/sinhala-unicode-on-android-google-nexus-one/

Comment: geffchang: Thank you for your cooperation. But this says how to place a new font in Android. But without language rendering rules, Asian languages not working correctly.Because Most of Asian languages having helping characters should place top bottom or other sides, instead of vowels in English.

Comment: it's a problem of font rendering, not Unicode. You can't requests to add a Unicode range to Android because as long as a platform supports Unicode, it'll support any codepoints in Unicode. But [rendering is much more complex](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/25359/42635)