# Enable tamil font without rooting the phone

Tags: rooting, browser, facebook, fonts, micromax-a87

I have Micromax a87 android phone,in my phone doesn't support the Tamil font in browsers and Facebook,YouTube. I searched for solution but shows that its possible only by rooting the mobile.I don't want to root my phone. Is it possible to display the Tamil font in Facebook and browsers without rooting the phone?

Comment: Check the answers to http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25359/how-to-make-an-android-device-to-display-complex-rendering-of-indic-characters which include suggestions for rooted and non-rooted phones.

Comment: I try without rooting use the Tamil Unicode Font only but still browser and facebook doesn't support the tamil font