# Lenovo IdeaTab A1000 not supporting addtional Language?

Tags: languages, localization, operating-system, lenovo-ideapad-tablet-a1

I'm using Lenovo IdeaTab A1000 and tried to display a text in malayalam. I found out that it doesn't have the language pack pre-installed. So I tried downloading a malayalam keyboard which was a success. But the problem is that when I type in some text using the malayalam keyboard I'm not able to see the text on the screen.

OS- Android - 4.1.2

Is there a problem with my tablet or with the lenovo OS? and are there any alternative to solve this problem ?

Please help me guys.
Thanks.

Comment: See also [this question about displaying Tamil writing](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/25359/12442)

Comment: @DanHulme I'm able to load the Tamil specific web pages with no hitch. But when I try to display the font in my app, I'm not able to see any text on the screen.